# Compiler error when using nested operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compilation

I have a URL class that overloads the ==, <, >, and != operators for simple comparison. The URL class has a string data member and some functions to act on the string. The operators work fine when tested with the URL class.

I also have a Page class that has a URL data member.  I am trying to overload the same operators in the Page class. Equality in the Page class is based on equality of their respective URLs, so I use the URL class boolean operators in comparing pages. This creates some compiler errors that I cannot figure out. Code for URL operators:

```
bool URL::operator ==(URL & u) const {
    //url is the string instance variable
    return url == u.GetURL();
}
```

Code for Page operators:

```
bool Page::operator ==(Page & p) const {
    //url is the URL instance variable of the Page class
    return url == p.GetURL();
}
```

This produces errors like so:

```
src/Page.cpp: In member function ‘bool Page::operator==(Page&) const’:
src/Page.cpp:21: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘((const Page*)this)->Page::url == Page::GetURL()()’
inc/URL.h:118: note: candidates are: bool URL::operator==(URL&) const
```

I predict that it is something dumb that I am forgetting. Will you prove me right?

**edit:**  Const correctness has bitten me in the bum. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you write C++ classes whose instance are meant to be used as values to be manipulated and compared, `const`-correctness is very important. Not only it helps you avoid compiler errors, it also lets the compiler do aggressive optimizations, like not loading variables more than once in the registers, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should have been:

```
bool URL::operator ==(const URL & u) const {
    //url is the string instance variable
    return url == u.GetURL();
}
```

And analogously for the other operators.

If you still get compiler errors, perhaps you haven't made `GetURL()` const as well:

```
std:string URL::GetURL() const {
    // whatever...
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I had to make both the Page class GetURL() and URL class GetURL() const functions. Dang brain.

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to point out that methods (ie the public interface) are there to protect external entities from changes in the implementation details. Also that a class is automatically a friend of itself (for the same reason) and thus just accessing the members of the other object is OK.

```
bool URL::operator ==(URL & u) const {
    //url is the string instance variable
    return url == u.GetURL();
}
```

Can be written like:

```
bool URL::operator ==(URL & rhs) const
{
    return url == rhs.url;  // No need to use GetURL()
}
```

In my mind this makes the code clearer (but this again is an opinion your tastes may vary)

Comment: Agreed. `GetURL()` is meant to be used outside the class.

Comment: Thanks, that does make it cleaner.

Comment: I've always gone the other way: `return GetURL() == rhs.GetURL();`. Function reuse.

Comment: @GMan: We are just checking state. If GetURL() has a side affect is that appropriate for testing state? But this is implementer call it all depends on the situation.